# firebase with map activity app error crashes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server, click

I want to add Firebase to google map activity but I put the following code to anywhere in the main activity but it still crashes app both on emulator and actual mobile here the code for firebase

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
```

When I move these 2 lines the app work perfectly again and when I add these 2 line to different normal app works fine no problem
Here is my class name and definition:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, 
           GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
           GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
           LocationListener {
```

thank you

Comment: Well, if there is crash. there must be crash log.

Comment: no crash log at all

Answer (score 0):

during the different version of dependency and firebase version.. check on:

```
enter code here
```

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'

Answer (score -1):

the other one was not working aswell at the beginning so what i did is to use normal activity without google map.